# I want to pull the SQl Server services details and SSRS, SSAS,SSIS

Tags: sql-server

I have tried to pull the SQL Services, Agent Service, SSRS Services running status. But I got only SQL, AGent services details am getting by using this query, Whereas I am not getting the SSRS, AS, IS services running status.

1. I have cross checked the services are up and running in the servers.

Query :- select * from sys.dm_server_services
Please help me

Comment: Do you need to get this using T-SQL? Or can you use other methods (WMI, Powershell, Batch script). If you have to get it from within T-SQL then you'll need to enable `xp_cmdshell` and give it sufficient rights to query running services

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft:

`sys.dm_server_services` returns only information about the SQL Server, Full-Text, and SQL Server Agent services in the current instance of SQL Server, so this is the expected behaviour.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-server-services-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: So how to get SSRS service running status , please guide me sir

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query that checks if the ReportServer database exists. This is the default database for SSRS. Of course this will fail if the SSRS was configured to use a custom name for its database.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = 'ReportServer')
  PRINT 'SSRS seems to be installed'
```

Comment: SSRS seems to be installed, ssrs Installed output i got

Comment: So this should answer your question on how to query the status of SSRS.

Comment: I didn't get you sir , pleae

Comment: With my posted statement you can query the existance of the ReportServer database. If it exists you have an indication if the SSRS service is installed.

Comment: Yes sir the DB is working fine , But i got stuck to get the details of the services details........of SSRS

Comment: My guess: You can't do this using T-SQL only. As Nick.McDermaid suggested above you can try using `xp_cmdshell`.